# JvCsvDataset Error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, jedi, jvcl

Using Delphi XE, I have a `JvCsvDataset` component that is loading a CSV file which has 27 fields.

When the component tries to load the file I get the following error :

> Too many fields, or too many long string fields in this record. You must increase the internal record size of the CsvDataSet.

When try it with a CSV file that has only 24 fields, it works fine.

How do I increase the internal record size of the `CsvDataSet`?

*I've tried to reach Warren Postma who wrote the component but did not hear back from him.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either specify the length of your fields to stay under the default limit or set the value of TextBufferSize to a bigger value before setting active to True.

From the last answer on
http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=4768